# Finite Difference Method for Integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

I know about finite difference formulas to approximate derivatives on a finite grid to numerically solve a PDE.

I am wondering if there are formulas to approximate integrals on a finite grid  in order to solve integral PDE's?

Comment: Yes, these are known as quadrature methods, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration).

Comment: I am more looking for a way to write an integral of a function as a Matrix times a vector

Comment: You can get an approximation as a matrix-vector product for the *antiderivative*, if you use a quadrature formula of the form $F(x_i) = \int \limits_0^{x_i} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \simeq \sum_{j=0}^i w_j f(x_j)$. But a *definite integral* of the form $\int \limits_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a scalar, and thus not a matrix-vector product.